# How to call data from another file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, rss

Hello my English is not so good.

I need to load the data from place HTML file 1 to $logos, but that doesn't work.
I don't know how to do it.
 
I believe the problem is here: `esc_attr($feed->readmore_logon);`.

File 1 :

```
<div class="field rssap-field-container1">
  <p><label for="rssap-display-readmore1">
    <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($feed->logo_readmore) : ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> value="1" name="logo_readmore" id="rssap-display-readmore1" />
    <?php esc_html_e('Display link to source', 'rss-autopilot'); ?>
    </label></p>
  <input type="text" size="50" name="readmore_logon" value="<?php echo esc_attr($feed->readmore_logon); ?>" />
  <span title="<?php esc_html_e('HTML allowed. Use %LINK% placeholder to add URL', 'rss-autopilot'); ?>" class="rss-tooltip">?</span>
</div>
```

File 2, the `esc_attr($feed->readmore_logon);` doesn't work.
Can somebody help?

```
$logos = esc_attr($feed->readmore_logon);
....
update_post_meta($postId, 'haus', $logos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx an everyon ho give a ansser !! i get it work thets is the code

```
 $logos = $this->readmore_logon;
```